# Why the progress bar does not appear?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, progress-bar

What I'm doing is make a activity to request JSON from an api.
I need the progress bar to show up during processing.
Here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WebService"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tips"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Tips: Press the button to get a random web link, then click the widget to open that link in a web view." />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="runOnNewThread"
            android:text="Request Link"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.538"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my activity

```
public class WebService extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "WebServiceActivity";

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    TextView resultText;
    ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_service);

        resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_textview);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    //button
    public void runOnNewThread(View view) throws InterruptedException {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        runnableThread runnableThread = new runnableThread();
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnableThread);
        thread.start();
        thread.join();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Thread ends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    class runnableThread implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JSONArray jArray;
            try {
                String url = NetworkUtil.validInput("https://api.publicapis.org/entries");
                String resp = NetworkUtil.httpResponse(new URL(url));
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(resp);
                jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("entries");
                JSONObject resultObj = jArray.getJSONObject(new Random().nextInt(1421));
                String API = resultObj.getString("API");
                String description = resultObj.getString("Description");
                String link = resultObj.getString("Link");

                handler.post(()->{
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    resultText.setText("");
                    resultText.append(API+"\n");
                    resultText.append(description+"\n");
                    resultText.append(link+"\n");
                });

            } catch (NetworkUtil.MyException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"MalformedURLException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"ProtocolException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"JSONException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }




    }

}
```

The toast works well, it will show up every time after clicking the button.
When I comment the `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)` in `runOnNewThread`function, the progress bar will show up but won't disappear, but if I leave the setVisibility here, the bar will never show up.
What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you put you visibility gone code in background thread it wont work because view wont run in background thread you should give listener in ui thread

```
   public void runOnNewThread(View view) throws InterruptedException {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                runnableThread runnableThread = new runnableThread();
                Thread thread = new Thread(runnableThread);
                thread.start();
                thread.join();
        // here is the problem Progress bar is a view  , vie canton run in background thread
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Thread ends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like after your toast message you've selected the option to disappear your progress bar.

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

you could try using

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the thread that you create in `runOnNewThread()` is useless: you create a new `Thread`, start it **and then wait until the thread completes**. Instead of writing

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnableThread);
    thread.start();
    thread.join();
```

you could just as well write

```
    runnableThread.run();
```

it would have the same effect.

Because you are blocking the UI thread with this you are calling `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` before the UI had time to show the progress bar.

---

The solution is the let the new thread run independently:

```
public void runOnNewThread(View view) throws InterruptedException {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    runnableThread runnableThread = new runnableThread();
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnableThread);
    thread.start();
}
```

And to move the `Toast.makeText(...).show();` and `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` to the end of the independent task:

```
class runnableThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JSONArray jArray;
        try {
            // I didn't include all the code here
        } catch (NetworkUtil.MyException e) {
            WebService.this.runOnUiThread(() ->
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            );
        // I also didn't include all the catch clauses
        } finally {
            WebService.this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                Toast.makeText(WebService.this, "Thread ends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            });
        }
    }
```